# Angular Application from html-template getting TypeError on template js

Tags: angular, typeerror, html-templates

Trying to create an angular(11) application, using this html template.https://bootstrapmade.com/flexstart-bootstrap-startup-template/

But getting this error on the template's js file.

```
main.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at on (main.js:29)
at main.js:113
at main.js:317
```

[image: error]
Added the css and js like this.

**index.html**, same as template index.html

```
<!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/remixicon/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And js, at **angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
              "src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js/",
              "src/assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/main.js"
            ]
```

and the `main.js` code

```
[![(function() {
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Easy selector helper function
   */
  const select = (el, all = false) => {
    el = el.trim()
    if (all) {
      return \[...document.querySelectorAll(el)\]
    } else {
      return document.querySelector(el)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Easy event listener function
   */
  const on = (type, el, listener, all = false) => {
    if (all) {
      select(el, all).forEach(e => e.addEventListener(type, listener))
    } else {
      select(el, all).addEventListener(type, listener)
    }
  }]
```

[image: main.js #29]

[image: main.js-#113]
[image: main.js #317]

Comment: I'm guessing line 18 returns null? is that element `.mobile-nav-toggle` rendered when this is being called?

Comment: Please share your html

Comment: Can you post a stackblitz demo?

Comment: typically with angular you would put code that relies on views (like tag with .mobile-nav-toggle) into ngOnInit()  to be sure you tag is there https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit   ...also would be good to post your html file

Answer (score 1):

Why you write JavaScript in **Angular** 11 application? TypeScript should be standard in modern **Angular** applications I would suggest you to use that instead if possible. [TypeScript config](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration)

> TypeScript is a primary language for Angular application development.

It must be that your code in `main.js` is getting executed before the `.mobile-nav-toggle` is ready. At that point the element is not available  so it is throwing `null`. So you must make `main.js` code to execute after the has  `.mobile-nav-toggle` rendered completely.

It's hard to locate exactly where your error occurs if you don't set up a **Stackblitz** example of your problem. Please do that to get a more precise answer. [Stackblitz Angular standard setup](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jljjjdvplyy)

Answer (score 0):

Replace /** Easy event listener function */ to given below in main.js.

```
const on = (type, el, listener, all = false) => {
    let selectEl = select(el, all)
    if (selectEl) {
        if (all) {
            selectEl.forEach(e => e.addEventListener(type, listener))
        } else {
            selectEl.addEventListener(type, listener)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI I am getting this error   "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'on' has already been declared"

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting your main.js (should be main.ts) code in an OnInit method.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  //...code goes here...
  const on = (type, el, listener, all = false) => {
    let selectEl = select(el, all)
    if (selectEl) {
        if (all) {
            selectEl.forEach(e => e.addEventListener(type, listener))
        } else {
            selectEl.addEventListener(type, listener)
        }
    }
  }
}
```